# Matplotlib Animate a box plot

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, boxplot

I'm trying to animate a box plot as data shifts over a time series.

I'm working off the matplotlib animate examples, which show how it works with the plot function, but that doesn't seem to carry over for a boxplot function:

**Code Works below, but changing the two lines to box plot gives me errors**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(np.arange(10))  # <-- ax.boxplot(np.arange(10))
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)


def update(data):
    line.set_ydata(data)  # < -- line = ax.boxplot(data)? 
    return line,


def data_gen():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield np.arange(10) + i
        i += .1

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Boxplot also doesn't seem to have a "set_data" function, or an "animated=True" parameter.

Essentially I'd like the animation to work the same as above, but depicting a box plot instead of a line plot.

Comment: [`mpl.pyplot.boxplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) returns a `dict` containing all the artists you would need to update. You would likely have to calculate all the quartiles yourself, and determine which artists to apply the data to. There is no single artist to update for a box plot.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out myself: The idea can be to clear the axes, and in each frame draw a new boxplot as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# line, = ax.boxplot(np.arange(10))  <-- not needed it seems
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)


def update(data):
    ax.cla()  # <-- clear the subplot otherwise boxplot shows previous frame
    ax.set_ylim(0, 20)
    ax.boxplot(x=data)  


def data_gen():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield np.arange(10) + i
        i += .1

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

```sh
# Unset socks proxy
unset all_proxy    
unset ALL_PROXY

# Install missing dependencies:
pip install pysocks

# Reset proxy
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I don't get it - what does proxy have to do with boxplots ??!